# How to update on value in ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, set

I'm trying to update the value of one ArrayList, I do not receive any IDE errors but when tryin to run I got out of index error. I was able to compile using regular int arrays.

I need something like the following but with arrayList:

```java
for (i = ar.length - 2; (i >= 0) && (ar[i] > sort); i--) {
    ar[i + 1] = ar[i];
    printArray(ar);
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```java
for (i = arr.size() - 2; (i >= 0) && (arr.get(i) > sort); i--) {
    arr.set(arr.get(i + 1), arr.get(i));
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList.set(int index, Object element)`. This method ask you the destination index as first parameter and the new element as second parameter. You are trying to set `arr.get(i)` to the `arr.get(i+1)` position. I think you're trying to set it to the position `i+1` instead:

```
for (i = arr.size()-2; (i >=0) && ( arr.get(i)>sort); i--) {
    arr.set(i+1, arr.get(i));
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with **set(int index, E element)**

Assume this is your array : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

At the first iteration:

int val = arr.get(i); //Val = 5
int index = arr.get(i+1); //index = 6

The error is here: **arr.set (index, val)** . As you see the "index" is more than the list size, due to which it is causing the issue.

Below peace of code avoids this issue:

```
for (int i = arr.size()-2 ; (i >=0) && (arr.get(i) > sort) ; i--){
            arr.set(arr.get(i), arr.get(i));
            System.out.println(arr);
        }
```